# Formula for tabulating daily running counts of a given column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

**I'm trying to** write a formula that gives a running count of *Issue*s for a given day. In other words: the output should enumerate each *Issue* for a given date (returning blank if *Issue* is blank), and then start again at 1 for the first issue in a subsequent date.

I've hard-coded the expected outputs in the "desired output" column (column `I`):

[image]

---

Sample **dataset** is in this [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yEmP613IpZA9QTupp0A7TBLuenudCCCwzYr4021jve4/edit#gid=1452618028). Key pieces:

- Column `B` contains the date
- Column `E` contains the T-shirt size severity of each Issue
- Column `F` contains a numerical translation of column `E`
- Column `G` contains a binary output of whether there was an Issue

---

In **my attempt** (column `J`), I've gotten close using

```
=ArrayFormula(MMULT((ROW($B3:$B)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW($B3:$B))) * EXACT($B3:$B,TRANSPOSE($B3:$B))^1, ($G3:$G)^1))
```

...but it's not quite what I want, as:

1. this repeats values instead of giving blanks (e.g. row 8, 11)
2. this gives 0s instead of giving blanks (e.g. row 3, 4)

See Validation (column `L`).

---

Any ideas on how to get to what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your formula in the `IF` function

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(F3:F="",,YOUR.....FORMULA))
```

In other words

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(F3:F="",, 
                   MMULT((ROW($B3:$B)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW($B3:$B))) * EXACT($B3:$B,TRANSPOSE($B3:$B))^1, ($G3:$G)^1) 
                      ))
```

Comment: WINNER! Thank you much.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Curious to see if this could be achieved by using row-by-row formulae rather than with one ArrayFormula. Posted [question 63947014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63947014/per-cell-formula-for-tabulating-daily-running-counts-of-a-given-column) to look at that.